# Why can't R's ifelse statements return vectors?

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization, r-faq

I've found R's ifelse statements to be pretty handy from time to time.  For example:

```
ifelse(TRUE,1,2)
# [1] 1
ifelse(FALSE,1,2)
# [1] 2
```

But I'm somewhat confused by the following behavior.

```
ifelse(TRUE,c(1,2),c(3,4))
# [1] 1
ifelse(FALSE,c(1,2),c(3,4))
# [1] 3
```

Is this a design choice that's above my paygrade?

Comment: little strange design for ifelse given the fact that simple if else works.

Comment: ifelse is a vectorized function. They should be used for different tasks.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The documentation for `ifelse` states:

> `ifelse` returns a value with the same
>   shape as `test` which is filled with
>   elements selected from either `yes` or
>   `no` depending on whether the element
>   of `test` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Since you are passing test values of length 1, you are getting results of length 1. If you pass longer test vectors, you will get longer results:

```
> ifelse(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
[1] 1 4
```

So `ifelse` is intended for the specific purpose of testing a vector of booleans and returning a vector of the same length, filled with elements taken from the (vector) `yes` and `no` arguments.

It is a common confusion, because of the function's name, to use this when really you want just a normal `if () {} else {}` construction instead.

Comment: Perhaps what you really wanted for the second set of statements was `if (TRUE) c(1,2) else c(3,4)`.

Answer (score 81):

I bet you want a simple `if` statement instead of `ifelse` - in R, `if` isn't just a control-flow structure, it can return a value:

```
> if(TRUE) c(1,2) else c(3,4)
[1] 1 2
> if(FALSE) c(1,2) else c(3,4)
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: @Ken, this works for me, even though I get what I need a constant warning `" Warning in if (req(inputval) == "All") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"` what should I do to get rid of this warning ?

Comment: @user5249203, the question and Ken's answer refer to the case where the condition is a single value, i.e., a vector of length 1. The warning indicates that `req(inputval)` has more elements. To get a single value the functions `any()` or `all()` might be useful.

Answer (score 18):

Note that you can circumvent the problem if you assign the result inside the `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(TRUE, a <- c(1,2), a <- c(3,4))
a
# [1] 1 2

ifelse(FALSE, a <- c(1,2), a <- c(3,4))
a
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: IMHO, this is encouraging to misuse the vectorized `ifelse()` function in place of a control flow `if ... else ...` for assignment. If the condition is a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, I would prefer to write `a <- if (TRUE) c(1,2) else c(3,4)` or `if (TRUE) a <- c(1,2) else a <- c(3,4)`

Comment: @Uwe though I don't think the difference in performance when using `ifelse` instead of `if`...`else` in case of a single condition can really be a problem and `ifelse` may be preferred in some cases inside code (simple guess here), I cannot disagree with you ;-). I just wanted to show a way with `ifelse`.

Comment: You could also slightly abuse `ifelse` and `list`s - `ifelse(TRUE, list(c(1,2)), list(c(3,4)) )[[1]]`

Answer (score 17):

use `if`, e.g.

```
> `if`(T,1:3,2:4)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that can actually provide the expected functionality of ifelse.

Comment: Is there any URL about \`if\` ?

Comment: @TakuroIkeda see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Answer (score 9):

yeah, I think ifelse() is really designed for when you have a big long vector of tests and want to map each to one of two options.  For example, I often do colors for plot() in this way:

```
plot(x,y, col = ifelse(x>2,  'red', 'blue'))
```

If you had a big long vector of tests but wanted pairs for outputs, you could use `sapply()` or `plyr`'s `llply()` or something, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the user just needs a `switch` statement instead of an `ifelse`. In that case:

```
condition <- TRUE
switch(2-condition, c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
#### [1] 1 2
```

(which is another syntax option of Ken Williams's answer)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach similar to that suggested by Cath, but it can work with existing pre-assigned vectors

It is based around using the `get()` like so:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
get(ifelse(TRUE, "a", "b"))
# [1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, using `if_else` from `dplyr` would have been helpful: `if_else` is more strict than `ifelse`, and throws an error for your case:

```r
library(dplyr)
if_else(TRUE,c(1,2),c(3,4))
#> `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Found on [everydropr](https://everydropr.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/how-to-return-a-vector-from-ifelse-statement/):

```
ifelse(rep(TRUE, length(c(1,2))), c(1,2),c(3,4))
#>[1] 1 2
```

Can replicate the result of your condition to return the desired length