# Why does ifelse convert a data.frame to a list: ifelse(TRUE, data.frame(1), 0)) != data.frame(1)?

Tags: class, function, r, if-statement

I want to return a data.frame from a function if TRUE, else return NA using `return(ifelse(condition, mydf, NA))`

However, ifelse strips the column names from the data.frame.

Why are these results different?

```
> data.frame(1)
  X1
1  1
> ifelse(TRUE, data.frame(1), NA)
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

Some additional insight from dput():

```
> dput(ifelse(TRUE, data.frame(1), 0))
list(1)
> dput(data.frame(1))
structure(list(X1 = 1), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`ifelse` is generally intended for vectorized comparisons, and has side-effects such as these: as it says in `?ifelse`,

```
‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’ ...
```

so in this case (`test` is a vector of length 1) it tries to convert the data frame to a 'vector' (list in this case) of length 1 ...

```
return(if (condition) mydf else NA)
```

As a general design point I try to return objects of the same structure no matter what, so I might prefer

```
if (!condition) mydf[] <- NA
return(mydf)
```

As a general rule, I find that R users (especially coming from other programming languages) start by using `if` exclusively, take a while to discover `ifelse`, then overuse it for a while, discovering later that you really want to use `if` in logical contexts.  A similar thing happens with `&` and `&&`.

See also:

- section 3.2 of Patrick Burns's [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) ...
- [Why can't R's ifelse statements return vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335830/why-cant-rs-ifelse-statements-return-vectors)

Comment: @Ben thanks for the tip. I did not realize `mydf[] <- NA` was an option.

Comment: @Ben would I then change the use of `if(is.na(myfn()))` to `if(sum(is.na(myfn()) >0)` in a subsequent function? I could post a separate question if you need clarification.

Comment: probably just `if(all(is.na(mydf)))` ?

Comment: or `if(any(is.na(mydf)))` to match your earlier logic

Comment: I think it would be better to return an empty data frame rather than one filled with missings.