# Dynamically determine if a dataframe column exists and mutate if it does

Tags: r, dplyr

I have code that pulls and processes data from a database based upon a client name. Some clients may have data that does not include a specific column name, e.g., `last_name` or `first_name`. For clients that do not use `last_name` or `first_name`, I don't care. For clients that *do* use either of those fields, I need to `mutate()` those columns with `toupper()` so that I can join on those standardized fields later in the ETL process.

Right now, I'm using a series of `if()` statements and some helper functions to look into the names of a dataframe then mutate if they exist. [I'm using `if()` statements because `ifelse()` is mostly vectorized and doesn't handle dataframes well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310733/why-does-ifelse-convert-a-data-frame-to-a-list-ifelsetrue-data-frame1-0)

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(256)

b <- data.frame(id = sample(1:100, 5, FALSE), 
                col_name = sample(1000:9999, 5, FALSE), 
                another_col = sample(1000:9999, 5, FALSE))

d <- data.frame(id = sample(1:100, 5, FALSE), 
                col_name = sample(1000:9999, 5, FALSE), 
                last_name = sample(letters, 5, FALSE))

mutate_first_last <- function(df){

  mutate_first_name <- function(df){
    df %>%
      mutate(first_name = first_name %>% toupper())
  }

  mutate_last_name <- function(df){
    df %>%
      mutate(last_name = last_name %>% toupper())
  }


  n <- c("first_name", "last_name") %in% names(df)

  if (n[1] & n[2]) return(df %>% mutate_first_name() %>% mutate_last_name())
  if (n[1] & !n[2]) return(df %>% mutate_first_name())
  if (!n[1] & n[2]) return(df %>% mutate_last_name())
  if (!n[1] & !n[2]) return(df)

}
```

I get what I expect to get this way

```
> b %>% mutate_first_last()
  id col_name another_col
1 48     8318        6207
2 39     7155        7170
3 16     4486        4321
4 55     2521        8024
5 15     1412        4875
> d %>% mutate_first_last()
  id col_name last_name
1 64     7438         A
2 43     4551         Q
3 48     7401         K
4 78     3682         Z
5 87     2554         J
```

but is this the best way to handle this kind of task? To dynamically look to see if a column name exists in a dataframe then mutate it if it does? It seems strange to have to have multiple `if()` statements in this function. **Is there a more streamlined way to process these data?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` with `one_of`, both from `dplyr`. This will mutate column only if it matches with one of `c("first_name", "last_name")`. If no match, it will generate a simple warning but you can ignore or suppress it.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one_of(c("first_name", "last_name")), toupper)

  id col_name last_name
1 19     7461         V
2 52     9651         H
3 56     1901         P
4 13     7866         Z
5 25     9527         U

# example with no match
b %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one_of(c("first_name", "last_name"))), toupper)

  id col_name another_col
1 34     9315        8686
2 26     5598        4124
3 17     3318        2182
4 32     1418        4369
5 49     4759        6680
Warning message:
Unknown variables: `first_name`, `last_name`
```

Here are a bunch of other `?select_helpers` in `dplyr` -

> These functions allow you to select variables based on their names.
>
> starts_with(): starts with a prefix
>
> ends_with(): ends with a prefix
>
> contains(): contains a literal string
>
> matches(): matches a regular expression
>
> num_range(): a numerical range like x01, x02, x03.
>
> one_of(): variables in character vector.
>
> everything(): all variables.

Answer (score 4):

#### Update dplyr 1.0.0

In `dplyr 1.0`, the scoped variants of mutate such as `_at` or `_all` were replaced by `across()`.

In addition, the best tidy_select helper for this case is `any_of` as it will perform on the variables which exist, but ignores those that don't exist (without warning message).

As result, you can write the following:

```
# purrr syntax
d %>% mutate(across(any_of(c("first_name", "last_name")), ~toupper(.x)))

# function name syntax
d %>% mutate(across(any_of(c("first_name", "last_name")), toupper))
```

which both return the mutated column

```
  id col_name last_name
1 19     4398         Q
2 72     1135         S
3 54     9767         V
4 60     4364         K
5 35     1564         X
```

while

```
b %>% mutate(across(any_of(c("first_name", "last_name")), toupper))
```

ignores the columns and thus returns (without warning message):

```
  id col_name another_col
1 42     7601        4482
2 22     1773        7072
3 47     2719        5884
4  1     9595        5945
5 81     8044        3927
```