# Unpack a data frame column into multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function that will mutate a column if it exists. If the column does exist, I return a data frame with two columns. I'd like help unpacking this data frame column, into its component columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

my_transformation = function(df){
  df %>% 
    mutate(across(any_of('cyl'), function(x) tibble(a = x + 3, b = x + 1)))
}

df_1 = as_tibble(mtcars)
df_2 = df_1 %>% select(-cyl)

my_transformation(df_1)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg cyl$a    $b  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       9     7  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       9     7  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     7     5  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     9     7  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7    11     9  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     9     7  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3    11     9  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     7     5  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     7     5  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     9     7  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # … with 22 more rows

my_transformation(df_2)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 10
#>      mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21    160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21    160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, when calling `my_transformation(df_1)`, there are two subcolumns: `cyl$a` and `cyl$b`. How do I get these to be regular columns?

I have tried `unnest(cyl)` but had no success.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. There is no need to use `across` if you only `mutate` a single column. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to solve for the fact that my data frame will sometimes have a column, and other times will not. From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998471/dynamically-determine-if-a-dataframe-column-exists-and-mutate-if-it-does I was hoping to use `across` and `any_of` to only mutate if a column exists. I will update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like

```r
mtcars %>% mutate(across(cyl, list(a = ~ .x + 3, b = ~ .x + 1)))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl_a cyl_b
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     9     7
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     9     7
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     7     5
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     9     7
# 5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    11     9
# 6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     9     7
# ...
```

Note that the `.fns` argument of `across` can take a `list` of (lambda) functions; so if you replace `function(x) tibble(a = ..., b = ...)` with `list(a = ~ ..., b = ~ ...)` the new `mutate` (`dplyr >= 1.0.0`) will automatically create columns `cyl_a` and `cyl_b`.

Answer (score 0):

So the only way I've found to drop the "nesting" for dataframe columns is by not supplying an LHS argument to `mutate` as [documented here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/#data-frame-columns)

Unfortunately, using `across` to check for missing columns is not possible, as it uses `.names` to assign something on the LHS.

Therefore, I'm taking the approach of [inserting the missing column if it is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857787/adding-column-if-it-does-not-exist) and then calling `mutate` without `across`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)

my_transformation = function(df){
  cols <- c(cyl = NA_real_)
  df %>% 
    add_column(!!!cols[!names(cols) %in% names(.)]) %>%
    mutate(tibble(a = cyl + 3, b = cyl + 1))
}

df_1 = as_tibble(mtcars)
df_2 = df_1 %>% select(-cyl)

my_transformation(df_1)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 13
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     a     b
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4     9     7
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4     9     7
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1     7     5
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1     9     7
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2    11     9
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1     9     7
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4    11     9
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2     7     5
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2     7     5
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4     9     7
#> # … with 22 more rows

my_transformation(df_2)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 13
#>      mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   cyl     a     b
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21    160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4    NA    NA    NA
#>  2  21    160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4    NA    NA    NA
#>  3  22.8  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1    NA    NA    NA
#>  4  21.4  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1    NA    NA    NA
#>  5  18.7  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2    NA    NA    NA
#>  6  18.1  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1    NA    NA    NA
#>  7  14.3  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4    NA    NA    NA
#>  8  24.4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2    NA    NA    NA
#>  9  22.8  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2    NA    NA    NA
#> 10  19.2  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4    NA    NA    NA
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Not a huge fan of the solution. but it does work. I'm considering creating a github issue for instances where you want to return an output data frame column, using `mutate` but only if an input column exists.