# Creating vectors with ifelse or if else

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I still get tripped up using `ifelse` and `if...else` when I want to create a `vector` or new `data.frame` variable.  The title of this question seems closely related, but does not address my issue: [Why can't R's ifelse statements return vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335830/why-cant-rs-ifelse-statements-return-vectors)

The code below shows my attempts to create the variables `my.data2$v1b` and `my.data2$v2b`.  I failed with `ifelse` and `if...else` then succeeded with a `for-loop` and with `apply`.

Is there a way to create `my.data2$v1b` and `my.data2$v2b` with `ifelse` or `if...else`?  I assume not based on my attempts and other `Stack Overflow` questions.  So, what is the canonical way of creating these variables in `R`?  Using `apply` works, but seems rather complex.  Using a `for-loop` works but I get the impression `for-loops` are to be avoided.

There are many questions about `ifelse`, but I did not locate one that addressed this specific question: given that `ifelse` and `if...else` do not seem to work, what is the best solution?  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Here is my data set:

```
my.data2 <- read.table(text = '
    refno  v1  v2 state1 state2 xday first last
      111  41  47      1      2   42     1    2
      111  41  47      1      2   42     2    1
      222  45  49      1      4   47     1    2
      222  45  49      1      4   47     2    1
      333  59  65      1      2   65     1    2
      333  59  65      1      2   65     2    1
      444  45  49      1      2   48     1    2
      444  45  49      1      2   48     2    1
      555  66  80      1      2   75     1    2
      555  66  80      1      2   75     2    1
      666 103 109      1      2  108     1    2
      666 103 109      1      2  108     2    1
      777  43  46      1      2   45     1    2
      777  43  46      1      2   45     2    1
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here are the desired vectors:

```
desired.data.v1b <- c(41,42, 45,47, 59,65, 45,48, 66,75, 103,108, 43,45)
desired.data.v2b <- c(42,47, 47,49, 65,65, 48,49, 75,80, 108,109, 45,46)
```

Here is where I start attempting to create these vectors:

```
v1b <- my.data2$v1
v2b <- my.data2$v2

# this ifelse does not work
my.data2$v1b < ifelse(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & my.data2$last  == 1, my.data2$xday, my.data2$v1)
my.data2$v2b < ifelse(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & my.data2$first == 1, my.data2$xday, my.data2$v2)

# this if...else does not work
if(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & my.data2$last  == 1) {v1b = my.data2$xday} else {v1b = my.data2$v1}
if(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & my.data2$first == 1) {v2b = my.data2$xday} else {v2b = my.data2$v2}

# this for-loop works
for(i in 1:nrow(my.data2)) {

     if(my.data2$state1[i] == 1 & my.data2$state2[i] %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$last[i]  == 1)  {v1b[i] = my.data2$xday[i]}
     if(my.data2$state1[i] == 1 & my.data2$state2[i] %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$last[i]  == 1)) {v1b[i] = my.data2$v1[i]  }

     if(my.data2$state1[i] == 1 & my.data2$state2[i] %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$first[i] == 1)  {v2b[i] = my.data2$xday[i]}
     if(my.data2$state1[i] == 1 & my.data2$state2[i] %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$first[i] == 1)) {v2b[i] = my.data2$v2[i]  }

}

all.equal(desired.data.v1b, v1b)
all.equal(desired.data.v2b, v2b)

my.data2$v1b <- v1b
my.data2$v2b <- v2b

# this apply works
my.v1 <- apply(my.data2, 1, function(x) {if (x['state1'] == 1 & x['state2'] %in% c(2,4) & x['last']  == 1) {x['v1b'] = x['xday']} else {x['v1b'] = x['v1']}})
my.v2 <- apply(my.data2, 1, function(x) {if (x['state1'] == 1 & x['state2'] %in% c(2,4) & x['first'] == 1) {x['v2b'] = x['xday']} else {x['v2b'] = x['v2']}})
names(my.v1) <- NULL
names(my.v2) <- NULL

all.equal(desired.data.v1b, my.v1)
all.equal(desired.data.v2b, my.v2)
```

**EDIT**

Maybe this is the canonical solution?

```
my.data2$v1b <- rep(-99, nrow(my.data2))
my.data2$v2b <- rep(-99, nrow(my.data2))

my.data2$v1b[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$last  == 1) ] <- my.data2$xday[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$last  == 1) ]
my.data2$v1b[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$last  == 1))] <- my.data2$v1[  (my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$last  == 1))]

my.data2$v2b[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$first == 1) ] <- my.data2$xday[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) &   my.data2$first == 1) ]
my.data2$v2b[(my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$first == 1))] <- my.data2$v2[  (my.data2$state1 == 1 & my.data2$state2 %in% c(2,4) & !(my.data2$first == 1))]

all.equal(desired.data.v1b, my.data2$v1b)
all.equal(desired.data.v2b, my.data2$v2b)
```

Comment: You won't believe it: your first ifelse statement is perfect, but somehow the `<-` sign got messed up as `<`. My personal advice is to avoid `<-` altogether and use only `=`...

Comment: Thank you.  I think this means it is time to step away from the computer for a while.

Comment: I think the apply solution is the most legible of your proposed options. Are you open to using `data.table`? That could give you another, rather more elegant option. Condensed in one statement: `as.data.table(my.data2)[, v1b := ifelse(state1 == 1 & state2 %in% c(2,4) & last == 1, xday, v1)]$v1b`.