# Ifelse using And

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a sample dataset below:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
   A       6       9  
   B       7      10
   C       8      11
   C       9      12
   D      10      13
```

How do I do an ifelse statement that says - "If Col1 does not have the values A and B, then make Col3 = Col2, if not, keep original values."

Final expected output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
   A       6       9  
   B       7      10
   C       8       8
   C       9       9
   D      10      10
```

This was my attempt but it didn't work:

```
df$Col3 <- ifelse(df$Col1!="A" & df$Col1!="B", df$Col2, df$Col3)
```

Comment: When I run your example it works. Is there something specific that goes wrong?

Comment: What's the structure of your df? Are the variables, factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
  mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col1 %in% c("A","B"),Col3,Col2))
```

Comment: Why do you need to load all `tidyverse` for this?

Comment: you don't.  `dplyr` is enough, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the true answer to your question:

[Why can't R's ifelse statements return vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335830/why-cant-rs-ifelse-statements-return-vectors)

As for code which will work, `case_when` is a much more useful implementation

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Col3 = case_when(
    Col1 %in% c("A","B") ~ Col3,
    TRUE ~ Col2
    )
  )
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to your linked question.

Comment: Did you read this? “So ifelse is intended for the specific purpose of testing a vector of booleans and returning a vector of the same length, filled with elements taken from the (vector) yes and no arguments.”

Comment: His vector is the same length as the intended result.  Yes, I read both questions.  Note that the comment above says nothing about the solution you have provided.  Just that the linked question is about something else entirely.

Comment: Reviewing the initial input, I was unable to produce an error at all (lol). That fact alone renders both my link & the solution useless! It is certainly unrelated as a result. Cheers