# how to assign value to a dataframe in ifelse query

Tags: r

I'm tring to assign dataframe value to a dataframe in ifelse query,but failed.I have no idea about that

```
df <- data.frame(x=c('a','g','s'),y=c(2,3,4))
df_1 <- ifelse(2>1,df,NULL)
```

execute and get the following result:

```
> df_1
[[1]]
[1] a g s
Error in if (n <= 1L || lenl[n] <= width) n else max(1L, which.max(lenl >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

the actual results should be

```
> df
  x y
1 a 2
2 g 3
3 s 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ifelse` function works with scalars and vectors, but maybe not with data frames.  Try using a regular `if-else` statement:

```
if (2 > 1) {
    df_1 <- df
}
else {
    df_1 <- NULL
}
```

Comment: You can do this with `ifelse`, too: `ifelse(2 > 1, df_1 <- df, df_1 <- NA)`

Comment: @andrew_reece Brilliant +1.  I had no idea that the predicate can also be an assignment.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, I can't claim credit though - found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695736/2799941