# Struggling with the ifelse function in R

Tags: function, if-statement

Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong. I don't understand the behaviour of the ifelse function in R. I expected that the ifelse function would return the whole list ids_match. However, these are the results I get with RStudio Version 1.3.1093 in the Console Window:

```
 cond1 = FALSE
 cond2 = FALSE
 cond3 = TRUE
 ids_match = list(1, 2, 3)
```

`ifelse(cond1 & cond2 & cond3, ids_match[1], ids_match)`

[[1]]
[1] 1

`ifelse(TRUE, ids_match[1], ids_match)`

[[1]]
[1] 1

`ifelse(FALSE, ids_match[1], ids_match)`

[[1]]
[1] 1

`ifelse(FALSE, "TRUE", "FALSE")`

[1] "FALSE"

`ifelse(TRUE, "TRUE", "FALSE")`

[1] "TRUE"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?ifelse`:

> Usage: ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> Description:
> ‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’ which is
> filled with elements selected from either ‘yes’ or ‘no’ depending
> on whether the element of ‘test’ is ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’.

Now, since `(cond1 & cond2 & cond3)` is a single boolean variable (i.e. `length(cond1 & cond2 & cond3) == 1`), your response will also have length of 1.

Also see related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335830/why-cant-rs-ifelse-statements-return-vectors).

Comment: glad to have helped! if you think my reply sufficiently answered your question, could I ask you to approve it? thanks!